Line breaks between columns in SQL Statement
I am using SSMS v18 and I have a question regarding the display/formatting of the query statement.
Example for the display of a statement:
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM table

What I want to achieve:
SELECT column1,
column2,
column3
FROM table

It would be much clearer for me if the columns were each displayed in a separate line. Can this be set somewhere in the settings?
When I add new tables via the Query Editor, the display always switches to the single-line view and I then always change this manually, which is of course tedious.
Thanks in advance.

It's not a setting it how you write the query. If you didn't add formatting to the query you write, it won't have formatting. I, however, also suggest you consider use of whitespace.

Thanks. Yes, this is clear to me. The thing is, I am not just writing the statement. For some parts I use the query editor - just for convenience, mostly for JOINs. After using the editor it changes the formatting of the whole statement.

Honestly, don't use the query editor; I don't think it's been updating since 2005, if not earlier. It lacks support for new features, uses deprecated features in others, and has many quirks and bugs.
